# How to retrieve original URL in Javascript (apache)

Tags: javascript, html, apache, url, httpd.conf

I have an html document, index.html, in the document root of my apache server. In my httpd.conf file, I have a RewriteRule that sends traffic to index.html if the user is missing a certain cookie (which they'll get on index.html).

I want to know what the original url the user entered is, before they were redirected to index.html. Is there a way to retrieve this and store it in a variable in Javascript?

Comment: You may check the existence of certain cookie with javascript, then store the original url with `sessionStorage` object and then on `index.js` redirect to url that you have in `sessionStorage`.

Comment: At what point would I be storing the original url in a sessionStorage object? 
The order this happens is:
`1. User enters url
2. User reaches apache
3. RewriteRule sends them to index.html
4. Script on index.html gives them a cookie and redirects back to a specific context path
5. User continues through apache to the endpoint`

As far as I'm aware, I can't store things in sessionStorage until I reach index.html, but I'm not sure how to reference the original url once I'm there.

Comment: well, you also can do like this:
1. pass original url to `index.html` as parameter in your rewriterule: `RewriteRule (...) index.html?to=%{REQUEST_URI}`.
2. read it, using JS in your `index.html` file: `if(window.location.search !== "") {/* check if not empty */
const redirectTo = window.location.search.replace("?to=", "");
window.location.href=redirectTo;
}`

Comment: Using your order of request things. `1 User enters URL 2. User reaches Apache 3. Apache sets referer cookie for RewriteRule to the referer in originating request header 4. User is redirected to index.html. 5. Voila, JS can get referer cookie, cookie user then redirect to originating URL.`